# Draw a polygon and fill it with a background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, polygon, fill

I am trying to draw a polygon with four points (A,B) (C,D) (E,F) (G,H) therefore not necessarily a rectangle.

I then want to apply a patterned image on to the polygon.

I have looked into `initWithPatternImage`, `colorWithPatternImage`, `UIBezierPath`, `CGContextStrokeLineSegments` but can't figure out how to put it all together.

Anybody got any ideas of how you could put them all together?

NOTE: I'm not using Open GL

Answer (score 4):

Not tested, but it should work like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myPatternImage];
    [color set];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:p1];
    [path addLineToPoint:p2];
    [path addLineToPoint:p3];
    [path addLineToPoint:p4];
    [path closePath]; // Implicitly does a line between p4 and p1
    [path fill]; // If you want it filled, or...
    [path stroke]; // ...if you want to draw the outline.
}
```

If you want to stroke it, you might want to set line width via `[path setLineWidth:5];` or something like that and also look into the other properties of [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) that control the line appearance.

Comment: Helpful answer (and works lol). One problem I have though is that the "background" is being filled in all white, instead of transparent like I need it to be. Got a one liner for me?  I've tried self.opaque = NO and self.layer.opaque = NO and also explicitly drawing the entire rect with clearColor (which turned the background black instead of white or transparent). Thanks for getting me 90% there!

Comment: @MichaelKernahan: It should simply be `self.opaque = NO; self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` in your view setup.

Comment: Ha! You are completely right and I am an idiot. I added my subclass of UIView into a xib, and placed the "transparent" stuff in the initWithFrame - which doesn't get called.  Simply updated in the XIB and voila. Thanks!